# Flex waiting for httpservice to return data

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, actionscript, flex4

Seriously. I'm getting really annoyed by Flex. Is there a way to make it wait for an httpservice to get its data without having to use a timer?

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
protected function loginUser(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(txtEmail.text == "" || txtPassword.text == "")
    {
        Alert.show("Please complete all fields!", "Oops!");
    }
    else
    {
        user = new User(txtEmail.text, txtPassword.text);
        user.login(user);

        var loginTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
        loginTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, dispatchLoginEvent);
        loginTimer.start()
    }
}
```

When I do `user.login()`, it sends a request with a HTTPservice from my external AS class. In the result event handler for this httpservice, I set a public variable to true or false, depending on whether the user's credentials are correctly in the DB.

I then use a getter to get that boolean value. However, without the timer, it always returns false because my code is faster than the event result handler. If that makes sense.

So I have to use a timer to stall my application for one second.. But seriously, that doesn't make sense to me. There has to be a better way, no?

I can provide more code if anyone's willing to help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: Note that in addition to my reply to you, if your Boolean variable is bindable with a plain ordinary metatag, you can listen for its property change event as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't completely understand my answer to your other question.

```
//Note the argument should NOT be a Mouse event, because that would be dispatched by a View.
//you should not have this kind of business logic in a View
protected function loginUser(event:UserEvent):void {
   //validate before even trying to create a user, since this
   //has the side effect of running an HTTPService call
   if (event.login != null && event.password != null) {
      user = new User(event.email, event.password);
      //these are plain old events dispatched by your user 
      //Note that strictly speaking a user should not be retrieving itself
      user.addEventListener('loginSuccess', onLoginSuccess);
      user.addEventListener('loginFailed', onLoginFailed);
   } else {
      dispatchEvent(new Event('incompleteUserDetails'));
   }

}

protected function onLoginSuccess(e:Event):void {
   //do your thing here
}

protected function onLoginFailed(e:Event):void {
   //trigger your error handling logic here
}
```

Your UserEvent Class should look something like this:

```
package service.event {
   public Class UserEvent extends Event {
      public static const REQUEST_LOGIN:String = 'requestLogin';
      //you may have other events that apply to users as well

      public var email:String;
      public var password:String;

     public function UserEvent (type:String, email:String, password:String):void {
         //I assume this will be dispatched from a View, given your existing code, so it will bubble by default
         super(tyoe, true, true);
         this.email=email;
         this.password=password;
     }
     override public function clone():Event {
        return new UserEvent(type, email, password);
     }
   }
}
```

You would dispatch that from the View based on the values of your email and password fields and listen for it higher up on the display list.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your plan if the login fails? Discard all the faulty Users that get created and start over?

Comment: I'm not sure :( We have to make a Flex application for uni, but we have hardly learnt anything and it's such hell to figure this stuff out.. I'll go over your code and try to understand it. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: This may take too long for you to pass your course, but you might want to consider going to as3dp.com to at least learn some foundational stuff about good architecture before you go out into the real world. The reality is that few people who do this for a living have the time or inclination to teach.

Comment: Thanks. Reality is that our teacher isn't too bright and doesn't know anything about best practices, etc. We're left on our own, basically. I'm still stuck on the timer thing here, but I doubt she'll care. I'll try to figure it out once I'm done with other parts of the application. Thanks for trying to help, I'll definitely check your code and the link you provided!

Comment: As long as the teacher is also running the code from your machine, this approach should work perfectly :-p. But I wouldn't want to try to predict a timer length that will work on unknown equipment.

Answer (score 0):

The correct pattern to use is a call back or an event listener on your User object.

```
protected function loginUser(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    ...

    user = new User(txtEmail.text, txtPassword.text);
    // pass a callback function to the login method 
    user.login(user, function(result:Boolean):void{
            // do something with the result
    });    
}
```

You'll have to excuse my ActionScript I haven't done any in a little while. But hopefully you get the idea. You should never get your self into a position of setting a timer to poll a boolean on an object in Flex, the answer is always to register a listener or some description.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to figure it out.. Not quite sure how your code works, but it's a start. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay, so I pass a callback function into the login function and make that function handle the result? The problem is, the result comes out of the `loginHandleResult(event:ResultEvent):void` function, not from the login function itself.. Quite confused.

Comment: My style of Flex tends to be more Javascript style with callbacks passed around. @Amy Blankenship's answer shows a more Flex style approach

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to teach newbies _first_ about functional programming. Javascript only lives the life of the HTML page, so there's not as much danger of memory leaks. Still, if that's a technique that appeals, check out http://www.developria.com/2010/12/functional-actionscript-part-1.html for more in-depth information about the plusses and minuses of that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are using HttpService object , I think the right way to go around is to use the "ResultEvent" and the "FaultEvent" on this HttpService object to process the data, after it has arrived.

You can see the following examples on how to use the HttpService object so that , it triggers a function after the data has been completely received from the server.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdc.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdc.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf66651-7ff3